# Cant run ES6 on android webviewer

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, babeljs

I am building a `cordova` app using `vuejs` for `android`, and I am using `ES6` syntax;
first of all it was not running on android studio emulator but it was running fine on my galaxy s5 (android 6), so I continued to debug from my phone. now I had to try on other phone like android 4.4 and it did not run will. after doing some researches I found out [that](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/)  the syntax of ES6 is not supported by webveiw of all android version. so I tried to use compiler `babel` to transpile `ES6` to `ES5`, but `vuejs` part crashed .

**this is my .babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
      "es2015",
  ],
}
```

**Q :** Is there a special configuration for `babel` with `vuejs`? If not, Is there alternative way in `cordova` to make `ES6` syntax work on all androids